# Is the returned proxy object of 'Proxy.newProxyInstance()' thread safe in java?

Tags: java, proxy, thread-safety, jedis

I'm created a proxy class for Jedis, then it can return resource to the pool and mark the broken resource automatically.

```java
public class JedisProxy implements InvocationHandler {

    private final JedisPool jedisPool;

    public JedisProxy(JedisPool pool) {
        this.jedisPool = pool;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

        Object result;
        Jedis jedis = obtainJedis();
        try {
            result = m.invoke(jedis, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JedisException("Unexpected proxy invocation exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            returnJedis(jedis);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Jedis obtainJedis() {
        Jedis jedis;
        jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        return jedis;
    }

    private void returnJedis(Jedis jedis) {
        try {
            if (jedis.isConnected()) {
                jedis.ping();
                jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);
            } else {
                jedisPool.returnBrokenResource(jedis);
            }
        } catch (JedisException e) {
            jedisPool.returnBrokenResource(jedis);
        }
    }
}
```

then use:

```java
JedisPool p = new JedisPool("10.32.16.19", 6379);
JedisCommands jc = (JedisCommands) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Jedis.class.getClassLoader(), Jedis.class.getInterfaces(), new JedisProxy(pool));
```

I know that the JedisPool is thread safe.

But is the "jc" object thread safe?  Is the proxy object of Proxy.newProxyInstance() thread safe?

I have viewed the source code of Proxy, the proxy object was create by JVM, I'm not familiar with JVM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the proxy object of Proxy.newProxyInstance() thread safe?

I don't see how the issue could possibly arise. It doesn't have any state except its InvocationHandler, and it is immutable. The question really is, is your InvocationHandler thread-safe?

Comment: thaks. You mean that if my InvocationHandler is thread-safe, the proxy object is thread-safe?

Comment: @CharlesHu I meant what I wrote. I don't see any need for you to reword it and ask me to confirm your rewording. My original answer answers your original question.